# How to apply Central Limit Theorem to Uniform Distribution to generate Normal Distrubution?

Tags: calculus, statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose I have a simple uniform continuous "unit" distribution X:

$$\begin{align*}
\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \implies \\
y < 0 : & P(X < y) = 0 \\
y \in [0,1] : & P(X < y) = y \\
y > 1 : & P(X < y) = 1 \\
\end{align*}$$

Let $Y_n$ be a random variable equal to the mean of $n$ independent variables with a distribution of X.

Let $Z_n$ be a random variable defined as $Y_n$ normalized.  That is:

$$\begin{align*}
Z_n = \frac{Y_n - mean(Y_n)}{stddev(Y_n)}
\end{align*}$$

Is it correct to say that as $i \rightarrow \infty$, $Z_i$ approaches the **standard normal distribution** by the **central limit thereom** ?

If so, then is there some way we can derive/calculate the formula for the normal distribution based on the formula for X above?  Perhaps using some calculus or whatever?  How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the typical [proof of the central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Proof_of_classical_CLT), you can show that the limit of the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) is $$e^{-t^2/2}$$ and that this is the characteristic function of a standard normal distribution. Finding a characteristic function and inverting one both use calculus.

Incidentally, the mean of the sum of $n$ of your $[0,1]$ independent uniform random variables is $\frac{n}{2}$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{n}{12}}$.  The characteristic function of a $[0,1]$ uniform distribution is $\dfrac{e^{it}-1}{it}$.