# Stupid probability question: central limit theorem and uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125492/how-to-apply-central-limit-theorem-to-uniform-distribution-to-generate-normal-di). The central limit theorem proves that the distribution of the average of $n$ uniform distributions (say, on the unit interval) converges in probability to a normal distribution. I've seen the proof, and it makes sense. But conceptually, it doesn't make sense to me. The average of $n$ values in the unit interval lies again in the unit interval. So how can their be  a non-zero probability that the average lies outside of the unit interval? Shouldn't it converge to a probability distribution function that is only non-zero in the unit interval?

Comment: Where does the central theorem say what you claim it says?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hence the "stupid"... :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing [the law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) and [the central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). The law of large numbers asserts:
$$
   \operatorname{plim}\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \left(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n\right) = \mathbb{E}(X)
$$
Notice that $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is going to belong to the unit interval in accord with your intuition.

The central limit theorem states:
$$
     \frac{ \frac{1}{n} \left(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n\right) - \mathbb{E}(X) }{ \sqrt{ \frac{\mathbb{Var}(X)}{n}}} \operatorname{\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}}\limits_{n\to\infty} Z
$$
where $Z$ is the standard normal random variable.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. It was the factor in the denominator I was missing. On Wikipedia, they phrased the same idea in a more confusing way. Thanks!

Comment: @Learner Thanks, I have corrected the names and added links.